# Android studio notification with alarm manager and broadcastreceiver not posting notification

Tags: android-studio, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to get my app to send a notification at a regular interval (the code below is set to 30 seconds for testing, but I would change that to monthly once working).

I am following code off another SO post.

The code runs without an error, but no notification is sent. Can anyone point me in the direction as to why this is not working.

Here is my activity code (REQUEST_CODE is set to 0):

```
    private void handleNotification() {

        Log.d(TAG, "jjjj3: " + "one" );


        Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this, ClassReciever.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HomePage.this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30 * 1000, pendingIntent);

        Log.d(TAG, "jjjj4: " + "two" );


    }
```

Here is my receiver class:

```
public class ClassReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "Receiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showNotification(context);
    }

    public void showNotification(Context context) {

        int reqCode = 0;

        Log.d(TAG, "jjjj5: " + "three" );

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddBudget.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, reqCode, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Some text");

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(reqCode, builder.build());

        Log.d(TAG, "jjjj6: " + "four" );


    }



}
```

Manifest:

```
        <receiver android:name= ".ClassReciever" />

    </application>
```

Comment: Are you able to see logs at least that you wrote inside showNotification()?

Comment: Yes I am - the two logs that I coded into ShowNotification() are showing up in my Logcat every 30 seconds. So the ShowNotification() method is running - there is just no notification being shown.

Comment: can you give us the device specifications that you are trying?

Comment: Hi, I hope I'm understanding you correctly, are you referring to the make etc of the phone on which I am running the app? I am using a Samsung A 30. Please let me know if I've misunderstood or if there is more detail you require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. There is nothing wrong with it. But if you want to target devices with `Android 8.0` and above that is `API 26+` you must create a notification channel before delivering the notification

```
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = getString(R.string.channel_name) // this will be displayed in app settings name it wisely 
        val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description) // this will be displayed in app settings name it wisely
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

Once you created the channel use that `CHANNEL_ID` to deliver notification like this :

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
```

For more information about this one or for java code you can check this [Create a Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java)